# I need the colors of my company logo edited.

Tags: logo, image-editing

I had a logo for my company designed and though Im happy with the logo itself, I want it in multiple colors so I can put it on hats and t-shirts of different colors. It is in a PNG file and I cant seem to edit it in Adobe Illustrator. Is this due to it being a PNG or just my ignorance of Adobe Illustrator? Any help would be tremendously appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

PNG is a raster graphics file format. You will NOT be able to edit the file in a vector editing program like Illustrator. However you could change the colors in a raster editing program like Photoshop or GIMP but I wouldn't recommend doing that. You need the vector version of the file that may be in a AI, EPS, SVG or PDF file format.

Comment: There is also another version in an AI format, however it has a background. I just need the logo itself being transparent so the color of the article it is on shows through the logo. Is it possible to remove the background fairly easily?

Comment: @Ryan Yes, it depends if the logo is still editable in Illustrator. The easiest way would be to use the Direct Select Tool (A) and select the background and delete. Then save in a file format that can be transparent like PNG for web and EPS for print.

Comment: I will give that a try. Thank you so much for the quick response and help!

Comment: I clicked the direct select tool and then selected the background, but I don't see a delete icon any where.

Comment: See the [Adobe help files - Lock, hide, and delete objects](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/locking-hiding-deleting-objects.html)

Comment: Thank you for that info. I was able to delete the background and export image as a jpeg, however now it has a big white square around it lol.  Any suggestions? I need to edit the image making it the only thing showing on a hat/t-shirt, then save it in jpeg format making it possible to upload. I apologize for my ignorance in graphic design.

Comment: JPG file format does NOT save any transparent information. You have to save as a transparent PNG file (preferably png-24) when saving.

Comment: @Ryan if you're planning on printing the logo, save it as a PDF (not PNG), after you've deleted your background.  PNG is still just a raster version and even though it allows for transparency, it's not good for print.  PDF is a vector format.